# Global vim plugin settings with vim-plug

Tags: plugins, settings, neovim

I recently started using plugins with Vim and decided to try out the vim-plug plugin manager (https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) and I really like its simplicity.

However, I don't know if the following occurs because I overlooked a step during the installation, but I always have to run `:PlugUpdate` in order to get the plugins to work when I open Vim in a directory that doesn't have a .vim directory with the autoload and plugged directories in it.

After running `:PlugUpdate` the plugins get reinstalled and a new .vim directory gets created in the current directory. I don't like the idea of having multiple .vim directories every time I start Vim on a different directory and want to load my plugins.

So my question is, is there a way of making vim plugins work globally with vim-plug (so that I don't have to run `:PlugUpdate` or `:PlugInstall` every time?

I am using Neovim 0.5 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to apply Vim instructions in Neovim. They are two different programs. In any case, use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I just started using Neovim a few days ago, i.e. I had the problem already when I used Vim. Besides I have a setup so that all the changes I do in my .vimrc are applied to Neovim. I have to admit, I don't know what you mean by plugin issue tracker (I searched for the term and didn't find anything related to the problem).

Comment: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're messing up the call to vim-plug. In your .vimrc where you add all your plugins make sure the path is correct. It should look something like this

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
```

note the `~/.vim/plugged`

Comment: That was it! Thank you!